# Checking for a complete file download in Java

Tags: java, io, download

Essentially, I'm pulling a relatively small .exe to a folder stored locally. What I'd like to do, ideally, is find when the file has finished downloading so I can perform some functions and then move on to the next file.

Here is a portion of the code:

```
String saveTo = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Applications\\Setup\\";
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(download.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(saveTo + "setup.exe");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
//Check if file is finished here. 
//Repeat function above for different file here
```

Comment: fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbcs, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE) does not execute on a seperate thread, thus it should not continue until the trasferFrom() is complete, right? Have you tested this?

Comment: I just tested a couple minutes ago, and you are correct. I'll edit the question to remove this bit, though the need to check if it's finished still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this. Make it a method and have it return true if it successfull finished or return false if it did not. It wont return until its complete. You pass in the file name to save and the download url.

```
private boolean saveFile(String fileName, URL download)
{
    try
    {          
        String saveTo = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\Applications\\Setup\\";

        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(download.openStream());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(saveTo + fileName);

        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        fos.close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I had some pretty good success with it, and it should cover everything for the purpose I intend. Just curious, is it possible to also verify file size or something of that nature to be sure the file is entirely downloaded after that method returns? It's probably unnecessary, but I am a bit curious.

Comment: According to the javadoc, if something happens to interrupt the transfer, an IOException is thrown, which we do catch.